Is the average of two identically distributed bounded martingales distributed in the same way?
I have seen this question and think it's sufficiently different (and well ranking on google) than the one I'm asking that makes it worth posting.
Lets say you have a barrier reflecting martingale, of distribution $M$, where the $i$th iteration has value $m[i]$. It is bounded by the inequalities:
$$a\leq m\left[n\right] \lt b $$
$$a+R<b, R>0$$
The barrier reflection process can be described as follows:

Let $r = r[i] \sim Uni[-R, R]$ represent random noise added to $m[i]$

$m[i]$ is then evolved by reflecting this noise across the bounds $a+R\lt b$


Barrier reflection figure
*
 \
  \   o
   \ /
-------------
     \
      O


$$m[i+1]=m[i]+\begin{cases} \\
(b - m[i]) - (m[i] + r - b) & m[i] + r >= b \\
r & a < m[i] + r < b \\
-(m[i] - a) + (a - (m[i] + r)) & m[i] + r < a
\end{cases}
\\
m[i+1] = \begin{cases}
2b + r - m[i] & m[i] + r > b \\
m[i] + r & a < m[i] + r < b \\
2a - m[i] - r & m[i]+r < a
\end{cases}$$
Is it then true that, for some identically distributed martingale $y[i]$, the average of $m$ and $y$ would share the same distribution as $M$?
Apologies for the formatting and lack of precision, it's been a while since I've wrangled latex/math in general

By the basics, a sum of two independent random variables is ditributed
by the convoution $$\text{Pr}[Z=X+Y<z] = \int \text{Pr}[Y<z-x]\ d\text{Pr[X<x]} $$ with density
$$d\text{Pr}[X<x] = \rho(x) \ dx$$
For two independent identically distributed $X, X'$
$$d\text{Pr}[Z=X+X'<z] = \int \partial_x \text{Pr}[X<z-x] \  d\text{Pr[X<x]} = \int \rho(z-x)\rho(x)<´\  dx$$
e.g. for two martingales equally distributed as $\text{RandomReal}(\ \{-\frac{1}{2},\  \ \frac{1}{2}\} \ )$
the convolution yields a martingale with a triangle distribution from $\{-1,\ 1\}$
